# Spring Boot + Spring Data + Spring MVC Encoding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding, utf-8

As is clear from the topic of the question, this is my stack of technologies. I have a problem encoding Russian characters.

Its my controller:

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/Product/ByQuery")
    public List getProductsByQuery(@RequestHeader(name = "query" , required = false) String query) {
        System.out.println(new String(query.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
        return productService.findByQuery(new String(query.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    }
}
```

its my Service :

```
    public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository productRepository;
  @Override
    public List<Product> findByQuery(String query) {
        List<DataModel.Product> productList = productRepository.findDistinctByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrCategoryContainingIgnoreCaseOrManufacturerContainingIgnoreCaseOrInformationValueContainingIgnoreCase(query,query,query,query);
        List<Product> resultProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
            int like = 0;
            int dislike = 0;

            for (Rating rating : productList.get(i).getRating()) {
                if (rating.getType().equals("Like")) {
                    like += 1;
                } else {
                    dislike += 1;
                }
            }
            resultProducts.add(modelMapper.map(productList.get(i), Product.class));
            resultProducts.get(i).setCommentCnt(productList.get(i).getComment().size());
            resultProducts.get(i).setLike(like);
            resultProducts.get(i).setDislike(dislike);
            resultProducts.get(i).setImage(productList.get(i).getImage().get(0).getUrl());
        }
        return resultProducts;
    }
        }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
    List<Product> findDistinctByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrCategoryContainingIgnoreCaseOrManufacturerContainingIgnoreCaseOrInformationValueContainingIgnoreCase(String name,String category, String manufacturer, String value);
}
```

Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"Service", "repository", "controller"})
@EntityScan("DataModel")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
public class CloudliquidApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public ProductService productService() {
        return new ProductServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Property :

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lopamoko</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudliquid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cloudliquid</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-annotation-plugin-repo</id>
            <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

What do I need to do, so that Russian characters will finally begin to be perceived?
Before moving to the spring, it helped me - new String (source.getBytes (), StandardCharsets.UTF-8)). But after the move it stopped working (in any format).

What else should you try? If anything, I transfer the data from Android (Retrofit).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where the problem with rendering Russian characters lies: In Spring Boot internals, in the repository/database, in the view rendering, or in the browser itself.  Q: Do you get any specific error messages anywhere?  Q: Are you able to isolate any parts where "Russian characters* are definitely *WORKING*?  Q: Is there an explicit "charset=" header in the HTML being sent to the browser?

Comment: You're taking a String, then transforming it to bytes using your platform's default encoding (which is unknown), and then transforming back those bytes to a String using ISO_8859_1, which only have 256 characters, and doesn't include any russian character. That makes no sense. In addition, instead of passing a query as a query parameter, you're passing it as a request header. Why? Just pass a QueryParam as a String, and use that String directly.

Comment: @JB Nizet - you're absolutely correct. I was just wondering if that's the *only* problem.  If it's just the query ... or if there are other problems besides.  Дима Гуманов: please know that  ISO_8859_1 != utf8.  Please read [this excellent article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Дима Гуманов - Q: Did you take JB Nizet's advice?  Is it "working"?  If not, could you please 1) clarify exactly what the problem is, 2) look through all of your logs for any specific error message(s), 3) Update your post with your current code, and the additional information.

Comment: @paulsm4 Sorry, I added such an idiotic string with conversion after the experiments - going through all possible encodings). The following really worked for me: I changed RequestHeaders to RequestParams and it all worked. Amazing.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  SUGGESTION: Please 1) post a response explaining the problem and copying/pasting the code changes you needed to make, and 2) "Accept" it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

move String query from @RequestHeader to @RequestParam